# GCP Google cloud App engine socket.io won't connect by wss

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, websocket, socket.io

I'm using nodejs and run a very simple socketserver based on the examples of Google. I've basically set everything according to how they explain, my environment is flex etc. But yet everytime my application client (angular based) produces the following error in the developer console

WebSocket connection to 'wss://' failed:  and falls back to https polling

It works perfectly fine when I run my application locally.

My socket app.js

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();


const userSocketIdMap = new Map();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

console.log("clienturl is:", process.env.clienturl);
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.clienturl, //this is filled with correct origin url
    credentials: true,
  },
  allowEIO3: true
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  io.emit('message', { message: `GET call` });
  res.status(200).send()
});


app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let message = ''
  if (req.body.message.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
    message = Buffer.from(req.body.message.data, 'base64').toString(
      'utf-8'
    );
  }

  let sender = '';
  let uid = '';
  if (req.body.message.hasOwnProperty('attributes')) {
    if (req.body.message.attributes.hasOwnProperty('sender')) {
      sender = req.body.message.attributes.sender;
    }
    if (req.body.message.attributes.hasOwnProperty('uid')) {
      uid = req.body.message.attributes.uid;
    }
  }

  if (uid) {
    let recipientSocketIds = userSocketIdMap.get(uid);
    if (recipientSocketIds) {
      for (let socketId of recipientSocketIds) {
        io.to(socketId).emit('message', { message: message, sender: sender, uid: uid });
      }
    }
  } else {
    io.emit('message', { message: message, sender: sender, uid: uid });
  }

  console.log({ message: message, sender: sender, uid: uid });
  res.status(200).send()

});

io.on('connection', socket => {

  let uid = socket.handshake.query.uid;

  if (!userSocketIdMap.has(uid)) {
    //when user is joining first time
    userSocketIdMap.set(uid, new Set([socket.id]));
  } else {
    //user had already joined from one client and now joining using another
    userSocketIdMap.delete(uid);
    userSocketIdMap.set(uid, new Set([socket.id]));
  }

  console.log('client connected', process.env.clienturl,userSocketIdMap)
});

io.on('disconnect', socket => {
  console.log('Got disconnect!');

 
});

if (module === require.main) {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
  });
}


module.exports = server;
```

And my app.yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
instances: 1
network:
 session_affinity: true
```